# Google App Engine Timeout running a Java Program

Tags: google-app-engine, timeout

I am running an optimization program in GAE.   The program runs on my laptop/eclipse and could potentially take up to 6-10 minutes to run.   It seems that GAE has a timeout of 60 secs and throws a 500 Error.

How do you increase the memory requirement for GAE?   How would you increase the timeout requirement to more than 10 min?  Is there something that I can do in GAE settings in Eclipse or do I have to get in touch with Google.

Answer (score 1):

I second @PatrickGray's answer.

Related note: the actual execution on GAE can often take longer than on the development server, so don't use the local execution time as a reference.

For increasing the memory requirement - you can configure [the module's instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Instance_scaling_and_class) as needed (with cost implications, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I was running in to this error in Google App Engine before.  You can't increase the timeout time, it's a hard limit.  I recommend the deferred library or using a Task Queue.  Here's how I solved my problem (in Python):

[How do I return data from a deferred task in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076128/how-do-i-return-data-from-a-deferred-task-in-google-app-engine)

Comment: Task is a good option, but it has a limit of 10 min on automatically scaled instances.

Comment: He says his upper end for execution time is 10 minutes.  I don't disagree with your answer, but I think he's doing all his processing inside of an HTTP request which is bad design to begin with.  Admittedly, I made this mistake at first, but then moved to using the deferred/task library instead of making the user wait inside the HTTP request.

Comment: The question clearly states "more than 10 min". Using a task is important - I don't argue with that.

Comment: appengine now supports more options that this answer gives, covered in the other answer.

Comment: Thank @Patrick for your suggestion.  Please see my reply to Andrei's answer.   I am now running into Java Heap Space issue (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)  on the deployed server.   Anyway to increase this during the execution of the engine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't need an automatic scaling instance for this program. Instances with [basic or manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/) give you as much time as you need to complete your tasks.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei for your suggestion.  I tried setting it up for Basic Scaling (B8) and set 15 min timeout, before trying something else.   This time the app engine ran for 8 min before sending the 500 Error.  I looked into the Logs in (Developers Console) and found that the engine ran out of Java Heap space.  Since B8, for 1024 Mb was the maximum offered.   Is there an alternative suggestion for this.  The engine is an optimization scheduling engine and the time and heap space required will depend on the problem size and complexity.

Comment: It's hard to give advice without knowing details, but if memory is the limitation, you can use Memcache - or even Datastore - to store data during the processing. You can get many GBs of dedicated Memcache if necessary.